# Send A Return Message To The Sender And Simply Print It Out

Tags: java, akka

I´m very new to Akka. I have created a simple Hello World App using it. 
The App is very simple, it sends a message to my simple Actor. What I want is to send a message back to the first sender of the message. I can´t get the return message. How can someone do that? Do the client have to implement a onReceive method? I have tried to comment in the code.

```
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;

    public class HelloActor extends UntypedActor {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Object o) throws Exception {
            if(o instanceof String){
                String message = (String)o;
                System.out.println(message);
                // how to get this response ? 
                getSender().tell("World",getSelf());
            }
        }
    }
```

The Client

```
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
    import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
    import akka.actor.Props;

    public class Client{

        public static void main(String[] args){
            ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("HelloWorldSystem");

            ActorRef listener = actorSystem.actorOf(new Props(HelloActor.class), "listener");
            // sending is OK but how to get the response?
            listener.tell("Hello");
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should use "ask" in order to obtain a `Future`, not "tell" in your main method

Comment: Thank you so much. I just used a Future and it worked. I Cannot answer my question with the correct implementation yet but I will.

Comment: So Mostly everything that runs in an actor is mostly in its own thread? but not all the time? what happens if you would like to share the same object between actors?

Comment: An actor by essence ensures that its code is processed by only a single thread at a time. If you need parallelization, you would need a pool of actors managed by a "router", in order to dispatch a same object to several actors in the same time. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/routing.html

Comment: You should read this great "little" book: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028789.do :)

Comment: Thanks I was looking through books about akka and most of them are too large. I will defiantly buy this one. Thanks again Mike!

Comment: @Mik378 It seems like they have changed their API and have introduced akka.actor.Inbox. The inbox was not there in 2.0.0. Their getting started examples have changed too. any thoughts about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is to use a Future:

```
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;
import akka.dispatch.*;
import akka.dispatch.Future;
import akka.pattern.Patterns;
import akka.util.Duration;
import akka.util.Timeout;

public class Client{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("HelloWorldSystem");
        ActorRef listener = actorSystem.actorOf(new Props(HelloActor.class), "listener");

        Timeout timeout = new Timeout(Duration.create(5, "seconds"));
        Future<Object> future = Patterns.ask(listener, "Hello", timeout);

        try{
            String result = (String) Await.result(future, timeout.duration());
            System.out.println(result);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```